# Style a file input with CSS to a button -> when no label is directly adjacent

Tags: css

I'd like to style a `file input` that a plugin I bought generates in the frontend to a nice CSS button.

I read many posts and articles how to style `file inputs` by using the `label` and hiding the `input`. However, in my case this doesn't work as the `label` **isn't directly adjacent** to the `input`.

Is there another way to somehow style this beautifully and get rid of the ugly grey default "choose file" button and the "no file chosen"?

**I'd very much appreciate any help!**

Many thanks

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AlphaX/0zanegc8/

```html
<p class="form-row thwcfe-input-field-wrapper" id="additional_upload_field" data-priority="40" data-rules="" data-rules-action="" data-validations="">

<label for="additional_upload" class="">Example files&nbsp;<span class="optional">(optional)</span></label>

<span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
<input type="hidden" class="thwcfe-checkout-file-value input-text thwcfe-input-field" name="additional_upload" id="additional_upload" value="" data-nonce="6467d03bb7">
<input type="file" class="thwcfe-checkout-file " name="additional_upload_file" id="additional_upload_file" placeholder="" value="" multiple="">

<span class="thwcfe-uloaded-files" style="display:none;">
<span class="thwcfe-upload-preview" style="margin-right:15px;">
</span></span>
<span class="thwcfe-file-upload-status" style="display:none;">
<img src="https://auraly.de/wp-content/plugins/WC plugin Themehigh checkout fiel editor-pro/public/assets/css/loading.gif" style="width:32px;"></span>

<span class="thwcfe-file-upload-msg" style="display:none; color:red;"></span>

</span>

</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, using a `label` is your best bet unless you decide to use a CSS framework like bootstrap to handle this for you.

I know you mentioned your labels not being adjacent to the input. If possible, just wrap an additional label around your input specifically for this purpose.

**Note:** *Make sure your label's `for` attribute matches up with your inputs `id`.*

See the example below:

```css
.fancy-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#additional_upload_file {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<p class="form-row thwcfe-input-field-wrapper" id="additional_upload_field" data-priority="40" data-rules="" data-rules-action="" data-validations="">

<label for="additional_upload" class="">Example files&nbsp;<span class="optional">(optional)</span></label>

<span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
<label for="additional_upload_file" class="fancy-upload">
FANCY UPLOAD
<input type="hidden" class="thwcfe-checkout-file-value input-text thwcfe-input-field" name="additional_upload" id="additional_upload" value="" data-nonce="6467d03bb7">
<input type="file" class="thwcfe-checkout-file " name="additional_upload_file" id="additional_upload_file" placeholder="" value="" multiple="">
</label>

<span class="thwcfe-uloaded-files" style="display:none;">
<span class="thwcfe-upload-preview" style="margin-right:15px;">
</span></span>
<span class="thwcfe-file-upload-status" style="display:none;">
<img src="https://auraly.de/wp-content/plugins/WC plugin Themehigh checkout fiel editor-pro/public/assets/css/loading.gif" style="width:32px;"></span>

<span class="thwcfe-file-upload-msg" style="display:none; color:red;"></span>

</span>

</p>
```

**EDIT:** You can also use the [::file-selector-button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button) CSS pseudo element but [it's not widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button#browser_compatibility).

```css
input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  border: 2px solid #6c5ce7;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  border-radius: .2em;
  background-color: #a29bfe;
  transition: 1s;
}

input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
  border: 2px solid #6c5ce7;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  border-radius: .2em;
  background-color: #a29bfe;
  transition: 1s;
}

input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button:hover {
  background-color: #81ecec;
  border: 2px solid #00cec9;
}

input[type=file]::file-selector-button:hover {
  background-color: #81ecec;
  border: 2px solid #00cec9;
}
```

```html
<p class="form-row thwcfe-input-field-wrapper" id="additional_upload_field" data-priority="40" data-rules="" data-rules-action="" data-validations="">

  <label for="additional_upload" class="">Example files&nbsp;<span class="optional">(optional)</span></label>

  <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
    <input type="hidden" class="thwcfe-checkout-file-value input-text thwcfe-input-field" name="additional_upload" id="additional_upload" value="" data-nonce="6467d03bb7">
    <input type="file" class="thwcfe-checkout-file " name="additional_upload_file" id="additional_upload_file" placeholder="" value="" multiple="">


    <span class="thwcfe-uloaded-files" style="display:none;">
    <span class="thwcfe-upload-preview" style="margin-right:15px;">
    </span></span>
  <span class="thwcfe-file-upload-status" style="display:none;">
    <img src="https://auraly.de/wp-content/plugins/WC plugin Themehigh checkout fiel editor-pro/public/assets/css/loading.gif" style="width:32px;"></span>

  <span class="thwcfe-file-upload-msg" style="display:none; color:red;"></span>

  </span>

</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have direct access to the template file. Is there any other way to style it without adding any elements directly into the code? Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer with another option. - Sadly, you are very limited if you don't have access to the template file.

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming! I'll try to see if the plugin developers have an idea. If no one else has an idea here, I'll accept your solution as final answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure thing, best of luck to you.